# How to sort the grid view whose column is listing integers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I am sorting the grid using DataView's "Sort" property. I am passing sort expression and the order in which the grid is to be sorted(ASC or DESC). But the problem is, since the column on which I am sorting the grid is listing the intergers, the sorting is happening as if it is a string. But I need integer sorting rather string sorting on that column.

The grid displays below as ascending order(string sorting)
55
77
8

But I need the columns to be displayed like this(Integer sorting)
8
55
77

What would be the solution .

Comment: can you add your current code to your question? it helps us providing a more relevant solution.

Comment: if (hdnSortDirection.Value == "ASC")
            {
                dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " DESC";
                //dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " DESC";
                hdnSortDirection.Value = "DESC";
            }
            else
            {
                dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
                //dv.Sort = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
                hdnSortDirection.Value = "ASC";
            }

            gvSOW.DataSource = dt;
            gvSOW.DataBind();

Answer (score 4):

I tried the below one.

dt.Columns.Add("SOWId", typeof(int));

You need to specify the type of the item template values before binding the data into data table by using 'typeof' keyword.

This solved the problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

In your DataGrid's BoundField column set the DataFormatString to:

DataFormatString="{0:D}"

This will tell that column that all of the cells contains integers and therefore the sorting will work correctly as you require.

See [BoundField.DataFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) for a list of properties you can assign the BoundField as.